# Nginx rtmps to Kick

Tags: nginx, stunnel

I try to connect via NGINX and STUNNEL to Kick.com and didnt get it work.

My NGINY Config is as follow abd the Stream to Facebook is working, what me confused more and more that kick not is working:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1978;
        chunk_size 8192;

        application hcvej48939 {
                live on;
                record off;
                allow publish all;
                #Twitch
                push rtmp://live-cdg.twitch.tv/app/live_XXXXXX;
                #Steam
                push rtmp://ingest-rtmp.broadcast.steamcontent.com/app/steam_xxxxxxx;
                #Boosty
                push rtmp://vsu.mycdn.me/input/XXXXXXXXX;
                #Facebook
                push rtmp://127.0.0.1:1948/rtmp/XXXXXXXXX;
                #Trovo
                #push rtmp://livepush.trovo.live/live/xxxxxxxxx;
                #TrovoOld
                push rtmp://livepush.trovo.live/live/xxxxxxxxxx;
                #Kick
                push rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/sk_us-west-2_XXXXXXXX;
        }

   }
}
```

The STUNNEL Config is as follow:

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4

# https://www.stunnel.org/faq.html
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1

debug = 4

[fb-live]
client = yes
accept = 1948
connect = live-api-s.facebook.com:443
verifyChain = no

[kick-live]
client = yes
accept = 1935
connect = XXXXXX.global-contribute.live-video.net:443
verifyChain = no
```

So can any one pls help to get it solved.... thanks!

I have try to change the Ports, to do it with Port 443 in the Stunnel Config and without.

At Time i try to test with Verifychain. But when i start the Stream, i cant stop it, so the Viewers think is bad to go on or offline.this Time i will start a third OBS and watsh if i get traced the rout to kick, to get out if there is another Port they use.

EDIT: I have try it only with OBS without Ports or anything and it works.... Did some one know the Settings from Port etc. what be used?

Comment: Looking for an answer to this too. The suggestion from Ivan didn't work for me, I get a -138 error from the ffmpeg command

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to copy the local rtmp stream over to the rtmps service without using the push directive in the nginx.conf but use **ffmpeg -c copy** flag.
This will take the stream 'as is' and send it over to kick's ingest server. Replace items in [ ] with your own values.

1. Send the OBS broadcast to the local rtmp server (rtmp://127.0.0.1/[appname]/[somekey]) and push the stream to regular rtmp services as usual with the push directive in the nginx.conf.
2. Continue to use the Stunnel for other services that use secure streaming [rtmps] (facebook)
3. **However**, to start the kick stream, no need to use Stunnel. Update the nginx.conf and remove the push to kick directive.
   To go live on kick, install ffmpeg and run the command:

   ffmpeg -i  rtmp://127.0.0.1/[appname]/[somekey] -c copy -f flv rtmps://[kick_stream_url]**/app/**[your_kick_key]

Take note of the "/app/" parameter added to the Kick URL that is not listed in the documentation but since it's a clone of Twitch, the parameter that is needed is shown in the URL ingest endpoints: *https://stream.twitch.tv/ingests/*

Happy Streaming!

P.S.
I like to use docker and build a container for each streaming service and keep things compartmentalized.

I recommend this docker image and add 'ffmpeg' to the install section of the Dockerfile document. Then, from the container's terminal, manually run the ffmpeg command.  *https://github.com/Dudoleitor/docker-nginx-rtmps*

Comment: This isn't working for me, are you sure the "rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/local" part of your suggestion is correct? On my end, the prompt window lists a few items (ending with libpostproc) and then just sits there.

Comment: i've updated the URL to clarify the key with [somekey] instead of 'local'. the same key must be used for the local rtmp server.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I see now what I misunderstood. Any idea why this doesn't work via the "traditional" NGINX + STunnel combination?